# Почему возникает ошибка Unexpected identifier при рендере шаблона Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
    <table class="table table-bordered tablesorter" id="packsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-head">
                <th scope="col">Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Courier</th>
                <th scope="col">Track</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="packs-table">
            <tr class='table-content' v-for="pack in packs">
                <td>{{pack.id}}</td>
                <td>{{pack.courier}}</td>
                <td v-if="(pack.courier == 'Fedex')">
                    <a :href="'http://www.fedex.com/Tracking?sum=n&ascend_header=1&clienttype=dotcom&spnlk=spnl0&initial=n&cntry_code=us&tracknumber_list=' +pack.track_number + '&language=english&track_number_0=' + pack.track_number + '&track_number_replace_0=' + pack.track_number" target='_blank'>{{pack.track_number}}</a>
                </td>
                <td v-else-if="(pack.courier == 'UPS')">
                    <a :href="'http://wwwapps.ups.com/etracking/tracking.cgi?TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&InquiryNumber1=' + pack.track_number + '&commit=Track%21" target='_blank'>pack.track_number</a>
                </td>
                <td v-else>{{pack.track_number}}</td>       
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Полный код:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GGPmZO

При использовании :href возникает ошибка, а мне нужно использовать :href для генерации ссылок. Если не биндить а использовать href хардкодом, то все в порядке. Как сгенерировать ссылки?

Ошибка:

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Failed to generate render function:
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in
>
>
> (found in )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дружище, проинспектируй атрибуты `:href=""`.

Я заметил, что ты скобки одинарные не закрываешь))

Попробуй для наглядности использовать апостофы ES2015

```
:href="`http://wwwapps.ups.com/etracking/tracking.cgi?TypeOfInquiryNumber=T&InquiryNumber1=${pack.track_number}&commit=Track%21`"
```